# Collapsing toolbar layout doesn't work when using horizontal recycler view inside nested scroll view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout, coordinator-layout

I have some problems with Collapsing Toolbar. I have following layout structure

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppbarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbar>
    <NestedScrollView>
        <HorizontalRecyclerView>
    </NestedScrollView>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem occurs only when I'am trying to scroll my `NestedScrollView` touching the `HorizontalRecyclerView`. In that case `CollapsingToolbar` doesn't collaps. Just `AppbarLayout` stay on it's place and `NestedScrollView` scroll under it. I've attached a video, where everything is clear. Can anyone explain the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be solved by adding `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` to inner `HorizontalRecyclerView`.

Comment: I edited the question removing the answer from the Question and post it here. All credits for the answer goes to the Asker.